# stopping harddisk spin-down on Asus EEE 1015PX (and other eee's as well)

Tags: hard-disk, asus

I have an Asus EEE 1015PX netbook. It runs Linux (debian) without any powersavings enabled. E.g. no harddisk idle/spin-down tooling is running.
Now constantly the harddisk spins down after it has been idle for half a minute or so.
I can disable this with `hdparm -B 255 /dev/sda` but this only works up to the next reboot. I tried using `hdparm -K 1 /dev/sda` to make this setting permanent but this gives an input/output error.
This seems to be an issue with other EEE systems as well: my mother has an EEE Shell (a pink one) running windows 7 and that one has a down-spinning drive as well.

My question now is: how can I make it stop doing this? It makes the system very unresponsive and opening terminal/su to root/hdparm/exit shell every time I reboot the laptop (or had it suspend for a while by closing the lid) is annoying as hell.

Answer (score 3):

my  recipe, I guess found on the internet, which I have followed with success on eee-netbook, says

1. make a file named `99-hdd-spin-fix.sh`. The important thing is starting with '99'.
2. make sure the file contains the following 2 lines:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   hdparm -B 255 /dev/sda
   ```
3. copy this file to 3 locations:

   ```
   /etc/acpi/start.d/
   /etc/acpi/suspend.d/
   /etc/acpi/resume.d/
   ```

   - not sure about necessity of the last two, but the following is a must:

   /etc/pm/sleep.d/

   - and of course the shell-scripts must be made executable. To put them out where one normally not can go, do sudo nautilus in a shell.

Answer (score 0):

As [this bug report](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=87451) indicates, there is a `/etc/default/hdparm` file in Debian's `hdparm` package, you should have a look at this... there might (I'm not sure, sorry, no Debian system at hand right now) be a `/etc/hdparm.conf`, too, which should be used to set these parameters at init time.

Comment: This unfortunately does not work: I closed the lid so that it goes into stand-by. Then I started it again and verified with hdparm -B /dev/sda that the value is 254 instead of the 255 I configured in /etc/default/hdparm. On the other hand, I found: http://www.jzab.de/content/ultimate-boot-cd-wdidle3-util-included which I'm going to give a try. Will probably help for my mother's asus with windows 7 as well.